# Wrong output from printf of a number

Tags: c, formatting, floating-point, printf

```
int main()
{
       double i=4;
       printf("%d",i);
       return 0;
}
```

Can anybody tell me why this program gives output of 0?

Comment: What behavior, specifically, were you expecting?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you create a `double` initialised with the value `4`, its 64 bits are filled according to the [IEEE-754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) for double-precision floating-point numbers. A float is divided into three parts: a *sign*, an *exponent*, and a *fraction* (also known as a *significand*, *coefficient*, or *mantissa*). The sign is one bit and denotes whether the number is positive or negative. The sizes of the other fields depend on the size of the number. To decode the number, the following formula is used:

1.*Fraction* × 2<sup>*Exponent* - 1023</sup>

In your example, the sign bit is 0 because the number is positive, the fractional part is 0 because the number is initialised as an integer, and the exponent part contains the value `1025` (2 with an offset of 1023). The result is:

1.0 × 2<sup>2</sup>

Or, as you would expect, `4`. The binary representation of the number (divided into sections) looks like this:

```
0 10000000001 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Or, in hexadecimal, `0x4010000000000000`. When passing a value to `printf` using the `%d` specifier, it attempts to read `sizeof(int)` bytes from the parameters you passed to it. In your case, `sizeof(int)` is `4`, or 32 bits. Since the first (rightmost) 32 bits of the 64-bit floating-point number you supply are all `0`, it stands to reason that `printf` produces `0` as its integer output. If you were to write:

```
printf("%d %d", i);
```

Then you might get `0 1074790400`, where the second number is equivalent to `0x40100000`. I hope you see why this happens. Other answers have already given the fix for this: use the `%f` format specifier and `printf` will correctly accept your `double`.

Comment: @delnan: Thanks! My floating-point is a bit shaky, but after a handful of edits I think I finally got it right. :P

Comment: Good explanation! Can you please explain about storing double in binary system a bit more.

Comment: @Jagan [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: What is Left most third byte. Why it is 00000001 ? Can somebody explain.

Comment: @Jagan: I edited my answer with some more information. The binary number had a stupid error that I fixed. It should make a little more sense now.

Comment: @ Jon Purdy : Now all doubts are gone ! It is very clear now. This thing(program) has  been bugging me for a long time.I sleep peacefully today!

Answer (score 8):

Jon Purdy gave you a wonderful explanation of why you were seeing this particular result.  However, bear in mind that the behavior is explicitly *undefined* by the language standard:

> 7.19.6.1.9: If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>248)</sup>  **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**.

(emphasis mine) where "undefined behavior" means

> 3.4.3.1: behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements

IOW, the compiler is under no obligation to produce a meaningful or correct result.  Most importantly, you cannot rely on the result being repeatable.  There's no guarantee that this program would output 0 on other platforms, or even on the same platform with different compiler settings (it *probably* will, but you don't want to rely on it).

Answer (score 2):

%d is for integers:

```
int main()
{

   int i=4;
   double f = 4;
   printf("%d",i); // prints 4
   printf("%0.f",f); // prints 4
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is happening when i write %d for  double.
Why it is printing 0 only . That is my question.

Comment: @Jagan: A `double` is not an integer.

Comment: @Jagan C is weakly typed. Especially, `printf` does not check that its arguments match the format string, nor does it convert them to make them match. What happened is that four bytes were read from the stack and these bytes happened to contain 0.

Answer (score 2):

Because the language allows you to screw up and you happily do it.

More specifically, '%d' is the formatting for an int and therefore printf("%d") consumes as many bytes from the arguments as an int takes. But a double is much larger, so printf only gets a bunch of zeros. Use '%lf'.

Answer (score 1):

Because `"%d"` specifies that you want to print an `int`, but `i` is a `double`.  Try `printf("%f\n");` instead (the `\n` specifies a new-line character).

Answer (score 1):

The *simple* answer to your question is, as others have said, that you're telling `printf`  to print a *integer* number (for example a variable of the type `int`) whilst passing it a *double-precision number* (as your variable is of the type `double`), which is wrong.

Here's a snippet from the `printf(3)` linux programmer's manual explaining the `%d` and `%f` *conversion specifiers*:

```
   d, i   The int argument is converted to signed decimal  notation.   The
          precision,  if any, gives the minimum number of digits that must
          appear; if the converted value  requires  fewer  digits,  it  is
          padded  on  the  left  with  zeros.  The default precision is 1.
          When 0 is printed with an explicit precision 0,  the  output  is
          empty.

   f, F   The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation
          in the style [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of  digits  after  the
          decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification.
          If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the  precision
          is  explicitly  zero,  no decimal-point character appears.  If a
          decimal point appears, at least one digit appears before it.
```

To make your current code work, you can do two things. The first alternative has already been suggested - substitute `%d` with `%f`.

The other thing you can do is to cast your `double` to an `int`, like this:

`printf("%d", (int) i);`

The more complex answer(addressing why `printf` acts like it does) was just answered briefly by Jon Purdy. For a more in-depth explanation, have a look at the wikipedia article relating to [floating point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_arithmetic) and [double precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision).

Answer (score 0):

Because i is a double and you tell printf to use it as if it were an int (%d).

Answer (score 0):

[@jagan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424716/), regarding the sub-question:

> What is Left most third byte. Why it is 00000001? Can somebody explain?"

`10000000001` is for `1025` in binary format.